# DisplayLink monitor alongside Intel

Tags: xorg, display, displaylink

I have a USB DisplayLink device that I've been able to get working with a custom Xorg configuration file. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 with the X server from saucy as a result of installing the saucy X server and kernel:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-lts-raring
```

I'm running the following kernel and X versions:

```
X.Org X Server 1.14.5
Release Date: 2013-12-12
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-37-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux chromeriver-laptop-tkocheran 3.11.0-20-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 21:32:55 UTC 2014 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.11.0-20-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgcryptotop-lvcryptotoproot ro cryptopts=target=cryptotop,source=/dev/disk/by-uuid/c7278631-aca2-47dd-a48f-44c1a5380e5f,lvm=vgcryptotop acpi_backlight=vendor dell_laptop.backlight=0 quiet splash
Build Date: 06 January 2014  01:37:48PM
xorg-server 2:1.14.5-1ubuntu2~saucy1~precise2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
```

Kernel:

```
3.11.0-20-generic
```

The problem I'm currently having is not being able to use both an external DisplayPort and an external USB DisplayLink display at the same time. I can use *either* the USB DisplayLink display *or* the DisplayPort display, but never both at the same time.

Here's my /etc/X11/xorg.conf file:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier      "Server Layout"
        Screen  0       "DisplayLinkScreen" 0 0
        Screen  1       "DefaultScreen" LeftOf "DisplayLinkScreen"
        #Option          "Xinerama" "On"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Configured Video Device"
        Driver          "intel"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "DefaultScreen"
        Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
        Device          "Configured Video Device"
        #DefaultDepth    16
        SubSection "Display"
                Depth   16
                Modes   "1920x1080"
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier "DisplayLinkDevice"
        driver  "fbdev"
        Option  "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "DisplayLinkMonitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "DisplayLinkScreen"
        Device          "DisplayLinkDevice"
        Monitor         "DisplayLinkMonitor"
        #DefaultDepth    16
        SubSection "Display"
            Depth   16
            Modes   "1920x1080"
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

The idea is simply to have a dual-display machine. Any ideas on why it can't start both the displays? Currently with the above setup, it only runs the DisplayLink USB display, the Intel display just shows console output.